# Deploy streamlit on GCP Cloud Run

Tags: google-cloud-run, streamlit

I deployed a streamlit application container to Google Cloud run, and I got an error saying that the requested URL /healthz was not found, I searched for that online and found that the /healthz path is somehow reserved by Google, so is there any proper way to fix that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have provided an answer below. Please check

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in this Cloud Run [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/issues#ah).healthz is reserved url in GCP Cloud Run

> It is not possible to use the following URL paths:
>
> - /eventlog
> - Paths starting with /_ah/
> - Some paths ending with z

There is a bug raised for this at [github](https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit/issues/3028). Which is still open further progress can be tracked there.

You can check this [github](https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit/issues/484#issuecomment-561773749) to deploy on App Engine, but it mentioned in this [discussion forum](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/has-anyone-deployed-to-google-cloud-platform/931/7) the recommended approach is to deploy on GKE

​

Comment: /healthz is reserved in GCP.  However, streamlit v1.18 has resolved this /healthz conflict.

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed in Streamlit version 1.18.

Here's a snippet of the [changelogs](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/changelog):

```
 All Streamlit endpoints (including /healthz) have been renamed to have a consistent pattern and avoid any clashes with reserved endpoints of GCP (notably Cloud Run and App Engine) (#5534).
```

Hope this helps.